# Time axis python

Tags: python, matplotlib, time

I have 2 questions, firstable, Im plotting a time series data with matplotlib, the time data is every minute, and its value  on Min/60/24 (example minute 1 = .00069) Could anyone give me a tip for plotting easily on H:M format on x axis. How could I set a specific range on this axis. Thanks

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you'll just plot it, and then set the x-axis labels to be the format you want. So if $t$ is your time variable that goes from 0 = 0:00 to 0.5 = 12:00 and 1 = 23:59 (or whatever), then set up your x-axis labels with format

```
"%d:%d"%(int(t*24),t*24*60-int(t*24)*60)
```

Or

```
"%d:%d"%(int(t*24)%24,(t*24*60)%60)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me so much

Comment: Good! Please remember to mark it up and mark it correct!